# AndroidManifest does not resolve a lot of symbols

Tags: android-manifest, react-native

My AndroidMenifest cannot resolve the symbols in red color. I think where I place those files and the name of the package is correct, right?

These symbols are not resolved no matter I use IntelliJ or Android Studio.

I tried Invalidate and Restart in Android Studio but it does not help. I tried `sudo ./gradlew clean` but it also does not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the snapshot I understand is AndroidManifest.xml that is reporting symbols in red. Now the manifest file contains information about the application as described  [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).
In your case you are adding layout specific information (such as icon name or theme) into the manifest file and this is not the purpose the file is made for.

You should instead use the **activity_main.xml** file to add this type of information. This file is usually stored into your res/layout directory. To have an example of this file generate any Android new project using Android studio and taking any available template, for example the "empty activity" template or the "basic activity template".